# CSS: float: none; being ignored

Tags: css, css-float

On [this website](http://masterwindowcleaners.com.au/), when the viewport width is reduced to 595px or below, the following CSS should apply:

```
@media (max-width:595px) {
    #header-left,#header-right {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

The browser is recognising the CSS, and it appears active, however, `#header-left` (which contains the logo) is not 100% wide, or is `#header-right` (which contains the phone number).

That is, `#header-left` & `#header-right` still try to take up half of the width, and appear side by side, instead of above and below each other.

Why is this occurring? Thanks.

Comment: You're missing an and between @media and ( max-width: 595px) you should also specify screen. Try putting !important after your CSS also

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? Because using it you can put your headers going full width on small screen using classes like `col-sm-12` or `col-xs-12`.
If not, try to use !important after width:100%; such as `width: 100% !important;`

Comment: All the other @media queries work fine without spaces in the ().

The browser is activating the `width: 100%;` rule (it is active in Firefox code inspector).

I am not using bootstrap Valentin. Adding !important does not change anything. The rule is still active, just not working properly.

Comment: Ok so I don't know how to solve this. But you definitely should use bootstrap as soon as you have CSS to do. It is a very useful and powerful tool and it prevents all kind of responsive problem if well used. Think about it in the future you won't be disappointed.

Comment: Thanks Valentin. It's not my website. I've been hired to make it responsive, but I've heard good things about Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position:absolulte;` from `#logo {position: absolute;top: 0px;left: 0px;}` and remove from `#menu`  Then your code works fine.

Comment: Thanks! Between view port widths 500px -> 595px, the #menu is not visible.

Comment: Fixed! I adjusted the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You should override the following commented rules in your css specific to the 595px size:

```
#logo {
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 0px; */
  /* left: 0px; */
}
#header-right {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 8px;
  /* text-align: right; */
}
#menu {
  /* position: absolute; */
  /*top: 80px;*/
  /*left: 0px;*/
  background: url(images/menu-bg.png) no-repeat;
  width: 960px;
  height: 55px;
}
```

**Note:** Override the commented rules